# Выдает неверный результат

Tags: c

Программа должна вывести сумму квадратов целых чисел
Границы заданы от 5 в квадрате до 9 в квадрате
При вводе 5 и 9 программа выдает результат 4369973 вместо 255
Из за чего это происходит ?

'''

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int min, max, sum;
    printf("Input min and max interger limit: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &min, &max);

    while (min != max)
    {
        for (int i = min*min; i <= max*max; ++i)
            sum = sum + i * i;
        printf("The sum of squares from %d to %d = %d \n", min*min,max*max,sum);
        printf("Input min and max interger limit again: ");
        scanf("%d %d", &min, &max);
    }
    printf("Well Done\n");
}
```

'''

Comment: Может, не `for (int i = min*min; i <= max*max; ++i)`, а `for (int i = min; i <= max; ++i)`?

Comment: Я новичок в C пожалуйста сильно не обзывайте

Comment: Да я вроде и не начинал :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я тут исправил *несколько* ошибок; сравните со своим кодом и разберитесь, зачем и почему эти исправления... Намекаю: чему равна сумма при входе в главный цикл? а при его повторении?

```
int main()
{
    int min, max, sum;
    printf("Input min and max interger limit: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &min, &max);

    while (min < max)
    {
        sum = 0;
        for (int i = min; i <= max; ++i)
            sum = sum + i * i;
        printf("The sum of squares from %d to %d = %d \n", min,max,sum);

        printf("Input min and max interger limit again: ");
        scanf("%d %d", &min, &max);
    }
    printf("Well Done\n");
}
```

Исправил также условие цикла на

```
while (min < max)
```

потому что если вы введете, скажем, 9 и 5 (а не 5 и 9) — то удивитесь результату :)

А вообще, можно просто написать, без цикла с суммированием:

```
printf("The sum of squares from %d to %d = %d \n",
       min,max,(max*(1 + max)*(1 + 2*max) - min*(1 + (2*min - 3)*min))/6);
```

Comment: Понял хорошо спасибо

Comment: Еще во  такой вопрос откуда берется число 4194687  ? когда мы не инициализируем переменную sum .

Comment: Ну, сумма квадратов от 25 до 81 дает 175541. Значит, в *неинициализированной* переменной `sum` у вас находилось мусорное значение 4019146 :) А могло бы быть любое другое. Неинициализированная переменная — это неопределенное поведение...

Comment: Понял спасибо .

Answer (score 1):

потому что вы делаете неправильный цикл:

```
    for (int i = min*min; i <= max*max; ++i)
        sum = sum + i * i;
```

255 будет если вы сложите суммы квадратов от 5 до 9, но никак не от 25 до 81:

```
255 = 25 + 36 + 49 + 64 + 81
```

т.е. ваш код должен быть такой:

```
    for (int i = min; i <= max; ++i)
        sum = sum + i * i;
```

конечно можно сделать указанный вами цикл, но это будет уже изврат

```
    for (int i = min*min; i <= max*max; i = (int(sqrt(i)) + 1) * (int(sqrt(i)) + 1))
        sum = sum + i;
```

P.S.

кроме того у вас также есть и другие ошибки:

1. не инициализирована переменная `sum` (`int sum = 0`)

Comment: Спасибо хорошо.